# Most efficient way of mapping column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I was wondering if `map` method was the best option when a simple mapping was necessary in a column, since using `map` or `apply` is [usually a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) .

Answer (score 0):

I compared the following functions for the simple case below. Please share if you have better alternatives.

```
# Case - Map the random number to its string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,7,size=(5000,1)), columns=['A'])
dikt = {1:'1',2:'2',3:'3',4:'4',5:'5',6:'6'}
```

## First function - using `map` method:

```
def f1():
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1['B'] = df['A'].map(dikt)
    return df1
```

Results:
[image]

## Second function - using `to_list` method in column:

```
def f2():
    df2 = df.copy()
    column_list = df2['A'].tolist()
    df2['B'] = [dikt[i] for i in column_list]
    return df2
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: hmmm, 5k is small dataframe, try test for 50k, 500k, 5M rows too.

Comment: You could have done `%timeit f2()`...`%timeit for x in range(100): f2()` has an overhead of for loop and range and `df.copy()`'s and performance should be tested on large df's atleast 100K size.

Comment: Here's [`timeit results I did on repl.it`](https://repl.it/repls/OccasionalThunderousQueries#main.py) `pd.Series.map` was 5X faster than *list comp* for dataframe of size 5 million.